# I use uv warp, but it doesn't match the map that helps me

Tags: uv

[image]

I watched this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY
In the video, a YouTuber creates an uv map that helps him position mouth.
In the video, the shape of the mouth changes according to the position when the YouTuber moves using the uv warp, but my mouth shape doesn't fit the position.
Why isn't the uv warp working properly for me?

[image]

Comment: hello, please pack your image, otherwise we won't be able to test

Comment: Mouths PNG Image: https://goo.gl/uAYaTK
Eyes PNG Image: https://goo.gl/x2lv52

Comment: could you please pack the image and share the file again, it will make the things simpler  ;)

Comment: I didn't know what pack was. But now that I know it, I've revised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply location and scale of the armature with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *Location* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *Scale* - or just use 1x *All Transformations* which applies also the *Rotation*.

Location should be (0, 0, 0) and Scale should be (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel's *Item* tab. The same data can be found in *Object Properties > Transformations*.

Do the same for the *Scale* of the *mouth* plane which is slightly scaled up (1.016).

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it works! haha